# Else condition issue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn Javascript and one of the problems I am trying to figure out is a function. I am having issues with the else statement I believe, but I am not sure what is wrong with it. I am getting an unexpected token syntax error of {...Which I know what that means. If I move `(numHours < 8)` under the else's {, that error goes away, but then doesn't run. Is my else condition done wrong?

```
var sleepCheck = function (numHours) {
    if (numHours => 8) {
        return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
    }    
    else (numHours < 8) {
        return "Get some more shut eye!";
    }
}   
sleepCheck(10);
sleepCheck(5);
sleepCheck(8);
```

Comment: `nunHours =>` should probably be `numHours >=`. It's also worth noting that since `>= 8` and `< 8` are mutually exclusive, a simple "if..else" will do, no need for that second `if` at all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: => is not >=. Voting to close. "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing another `if`

Change:

```
else (numHours < 8) {
```

to

```
else if (numHours < 8) {
```

However, you don't really need that second condition at all because if `numHours` is **NOT** greater than or equal to 8 (i.e. the first `if` condition is `false`) then you can just use `else` without checking if `numHours` is less than 8 because it has to be since it's not greater than or equal to 8.

Your conditions can just be:

```
if (numHours => 8) {
    return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
}    
else {  // has to be < 8 if not >= 8
    return "Get some more shut eye!";
}
```

*Note*: you mispelled `nunHours` in your first condition

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I caught the `nunhours` right after posting and the wrong >= sign... I am trying to learn it on a site and it required it be this way. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Otherwise you can simply remove the (numHours < 8) and have something like that :

```
if (numHours >= 8) {
    return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
}    
else {
    return "Get some more shut eye!";
}
```

This will enter in the else only if it doesn't fit the if condition. If you want only two different behaviour depending on the value this is the best way  to achieve that otherwise you can use else if like that :

```
if (numHours >= 8) {
    return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
}    
else if (numHours == 7) {
    return "Get some more shut eye!";
}
else if (numHours == 6) {
    return "Get some more shut eye!";
}
else {
return "less than 6";
}
```

Hope it is clear :)